# What kind of ribes is this?

Tags: species-identification, botany, fruit

I have a plant in my USDA zone 5 garden that appears to be in the ribes genus.

[image]

Details:

- The location is east of Toronto (Ontario, Canada).
- The plant is currently flowering (today is May 18th, 2019).
- It is approx 4 feet tall.
- The plant flowers every year, but does not set fruit (not self-fruitful).

More photos here:

1. https://i.stack.imgur.com/coEp5.jpg
2. https://i.stack.imgur.com/wv0TA.jpg
3. https://i.stack.imgur.com/pFmtk.jpg
4. https://i.stack.imgur.com/KvjGe.jpg

**What species is it?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is ***Ribes americanum* or wild black currant**.

I'm basing this on page 306 of **Newcomb's Wildflower Guide**, an excellent source for the Eastern US and some of Canada.  On that page we have two main choices:

> 1. Base of flowers prickly or bristly... or
> 2. Base of flowers not prickly or bristly...

Your *excellent* pictures suggest that your specimen is in category 2.

From there, we have:

> a. Flowers solitary or 2-3 in a cluster; branches bearing a few thorns. or
>
> b. Flowers 5 or more in racemes.

Your specimen looks to have quite a few flowers, so in category 2b we have a choice of *Ribes americanum*:

> Whitish or yellowish flowers, longer than wide (and fruit black, you can check later I guess),

or *Ribes sativum*:

> Greenish flowers, wider than long (and fruit red).

Color in the white/green/yellow range is a bit subjective, but your flowers look longer than wide, hence *Ribes americanum*.

Of course, with this in mind you might re-inspect the plant and refine this a bit.

Comment: I'm glad the photos worked out. I was just using an old phone camera. The key seemed to be to take lots of photos; one of them was bound to be in focus. :)